# Better way to check if all array values by key are empty?

Tags: php, arrays, optimization, key

I created function to check if all values for given key are empty. It work fine but I would like to know if this function can be optimized or reduced ?

```
function array_key_empty($array, $key)
{
    if (is_array($array)) {
        foreach ($array as $item) {
            if (array_key_exists($key, $item)) {
                if (!empty(trim($item[$key]))) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

**Examples :**

```
$array = [
    ['code' => '', 'description' => 'Oh there is a beautiful product !', 'price' => 10],
    ['code' => '', 'description' => 'Another beautiful product', 'price' => 20],
    ['code' => '', 'description' => 'Hey where will you stop ?!', 'price' => 30]
];

array_key_empty($array, 'code'); // true because all code are empty

$array = [
    ['code' => 'Yup !', 'description' => 'Oh there is a beautiful product !', 'price' => 10],
    ['code' => '', 'description' => 'Another beautiful product', 'price' => 20],
    ['code' => '', 'description' => 'Hey where will you stop ?!', 'price' => 30]
];

array_key_empty($array, 'code'); // false because Yup...
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be posted on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ooops sorry I forget codereview !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```
if(count(array_filter( array_map('trim',array_column($array,'code'))))==0){
  echo "all values are empty";
}
```

Output:-https://eval.in/842810

Comment: Thanks ! Bu I need to trim each value and in this case, if a value contain space it consider has not empty.

Comment: @Damosse31  let me add that too

Comment: @Damosse31  check now

Comment: Awesome lines reducing ! Thanks man ! I just need to check if array is given to avoid Warning but it's perfect !

Comment: @Damosse31  check and if have any issue then let me know, otherwise don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.Thanks

Comment: Just have an Exception if value is an array like 'code' => []

Comment: Exception because trim can't take an array

Comment: @Damosse31  you need to provide all options at the time when you asked question. I will update my answer for that after some-time

Comment: Yep I will do but my initial code contain a trim to check string is empty or not and also check if given array is really an array.

Comment: @Damosse31  it will be best if you can do that much

Comment: Ok will do for future questions

Answer (score 1):

you can reduce your function to a single line like this :

```
<?php

$array = [
    ['code' => '', 'description' => 'Oh there is a beautiful product !', 'price' => 10],
    ['code' => '', 'description' => 'Another beautiful product', 'price' => 20],
    ['code' => '', 'description' => 'Hey where will you stop ?!', 'price' => 30]
];


function array_key_empty($array, $key)
{
     return is_array($array) && empty(array_map('trim', array_filter(array_column($array, $key))));
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r(array_key_empty($array, 'code'));
```

**output:**

```
1
```